# CSS анимация при скролле в обе стороны

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Добрый день, ранее для анимации использовал `wow.js` и `animate.css` но нужно сделать что-бы анимация так же стартовала каждый раз когда элемент в поле зрения. Если ли решение с помощью `wow.js` или может есть какой-то другой плагин? Заранее спасибо!

Comment: 5-10 строк кода. И на кой плагин использовать...?  Хотя не мое дело, хозяин барин...  А сам, что сделал? Людям гадать, что да как сделано и что надо поменять?

Answer (score 1):

Нашёл такое решение

```js
// Returns true if the specified element has been scrolled into the viewport.
function isElementInViewport(elem) {
    var $elem = $(elem);

    // Get the scroll position of the page.
    var scrollElem = ((navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('webkit') != -1) ? 'body' : 'html');
    var viewportTop = $(scrollElem).scrollTop();
    var viewportBottom = viewportTop + $(window).height();

    // Get the position of the element on the page.
    var elemTop = Math.round( $elem.offset().top );
    var elemBottom = elemTop + $elem.height();

    return ((elemTop < viewportBottom) && (elemBottom > viewportTop));
}

// Check if it's time to start the animation.
function checkAnimation() {
    var $elem = $('.YOUR_CLASS');

    if (isElementInViewport($elem)) {
        // Start the animation
        $elem.addClass('fadeIn animated');
    } else {
        $elem.removeClass('fadeIn animated');
    }
}

// Capture scroll events
$(window).scroll(function(){
    checkAnimation();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5RNhL/225/)